# Check if a permutation of a string can become a palindrome

Tags: string, algorithm, palindrome

> Write a method to test if a string meets the preconditions to become a palindrome.
>
> Eg:
>
> ```
> Input    | Output
> mmo      | True  
> yakak    | True  
> travel   | False
> ```

I'm thinking of this approach:

1. Make a suffix tree for all permutation of T such that T$Reverse(T)#
2. Check for all permutation for same node

Am I missing anything?

Comment: You simply have to permutate all characters and check each resulting sequence whether its reverse is equal to the sequence itself.

Comment: Do you mean: is there a permutation of the string that is a palindrome? The title and the question have mistakes, I'm afraid.

Comment: testing that you don't need to do permutation at all. you just need to do some auditing: if the string length is odd, there should be one and only one char whose total number over the string is odd; if the string length is even, all chars' total numbers over the string should be even. if that's the case, you are really complicating this problem.

Comment: So basically you want to determine if you can rearrange the characters of the input string into a palindrome? If so, then the answer is "yes" if 1) the length is even, and every unique character occurs a multiple of 2, or 2) the length is odd, and every unique character occurs a multiple of 2 except one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really all you're looking for is if all (or all but one) of the letters are paired off. As long as they are, then they will be able to be turned into a palindrome.

So it would be something like...

```
bool canBeTurnedIntoAPalindrome(string drome)
{
  // If we've found a letter that has no match, the center letter.
  bool centerUsed = false;
  char center;

  char c;
  int count = 0;

  // TODO: Remove whitespace from the string.

  // Check each letter to see if there's an even number of it.
  for(int i = 0; i<drome.length(); i++)
  {
    c = drome[i];
    count = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < drome.length(); j++)
      if (drome[j] == c)
         count++;

    // If there was an odd number of those entries
    // and the center is already used, then a palindrome
    // is impossible, so return false.
    if (count % 2 == 1)
    {
      if (centerUsed == true && center != c)
        return false;
      else
      {
        centerused = true;
        center = c;   // This is so when we encounter it again it
                      // doesn't count it as another separate center.
      }
    }
  }
  // If we made it all the way through that loop without returning false, then
  return true;
}
```

This isn't the most efficient (it's counting letters as many times as it comes across them, even if they've been counted already) but it does work.

Answer (score 21):

All you need to do is check that there's at most one character with an odd number of occurrences. Here's a Java example:

```java
private static boolean canMakePalindrom(String s) {
    Map<Character, Integer> countChars = new HashMap<>();

    // Count the occurrences of each character
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        Integer count = countChars.get(c);
        if (count == null) {
            count = Integer.valueOf(1);
        } else {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        countChars.put(c, count);
    }

    boolean hasOdd = false;
    for (int count : countChars.values()) {
        if (count % 2 == 1) {
            if (hasOdd) {
                // Found two chars with odd counts - return false;
                return false;
            } else {
                // Found the first char with odd count
                hasOdd = true;
            }
        }
     }

     // Haven't found more than one char with an odd count
     return true;
}
```

EDIT4 (yes - these are ordered to make sense, but numbered by chronological order):
The above implementation has a built in inefficiency. I don't think the first iteration over the string can be avoided, but there's no real reason to keep a count of all the occurrences - it's enough to just keep track of those with the an odd count. For this usecase, it's enough to keep track of each character we encounter (e.g., with a `Set`), and remove it when we encounter it again. In the worst case, where all the characters in the string are different, the performance is comparable, but in the common case, where there are several occurrences of each character, this implementation improves both time and memory complexity of the second loop (which is now reduced to a single condition) dramatically:

```java
private static boolean canMakePalindrom(String s) {
    Set<Character> oddChars = new HashSet<>();

    // Go over the characters
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        // Record the encountered character:
        if (!oddChars.add(c)) {
            // If the char was already encountered, remove it - 
            // this is an even time we encounter it
            oddChars.remove(c);
        }
    }

    // Check the number of characters with odd counts:
    return oddChars.size() <= 1;
}
```

EDIT3 (yes - these are ordered to make sense, but numbered by chronological order):
Java 8 provides a fluent streaming API which could be used to create an implementation similar to the Python one-liners below:

```java
private static boolean canMakePalindrom(String s) {
    return s.chars()
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                           Collectors.counting()))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> p % 2 == 1)
            .count() <= 1;
}
```

EDIT:
Python built-in functions and comprehension capabilities make this too attractive not to publish this one liner solution.  It's probably less efficient than the aforementioned Java one, but is quite elegant:

```py
from collections import Counter

def canMakePalindrom(s):
    return len([v for v in Counter(s).values() if v % 2 == 1]) <= 1
```

EDIT2:
Or, an even cleaner approach as proposed by @DSM in the comments:

```py
from collections import Counter

def canMakePalindrom(s):
    return sum(v % 2 == 1 for v in Counter(s).values()) <= 1
```

Comment: What about 'aa'? isn't that a palindrome not detected by your solution?

Comment: @MAA Why would you think that `"aa"` ins't detected by any of these solutions? I've ran all five of them against `"aa"`, and they all return true.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking that there aren't any characters with odd occurrences, but that ain't a problem.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of counting how many times each letter occurs, another approach keeps track of whether a letter has occurred an odd or even number of times.  If a letter has occurred an even number of times, you don’t need to worry about it, and only need to keep track of the odd occurrences in a set.  In Java:

```java
public static boolean canMakePalindrome(String s) {
    Set<Character> oddLetters = new HashSet<>();
    for ( char c : s.toCharArray() ) {
        if ( ! oddLetters.remove(c) ) {
            oddLetters.add(c);
        }
    }
    return oddLetters.size() <= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this is how I understand it:

> If the input string can be rearranged into a palindrome, output "True", otherwise output "False".

Then you can use these simple rules:

1. If the length is even, every unique character in the input has to occur a multiple of 2 times.
2. If the length is odd, every unique character except one has to occur a multiple of 2 times. Only 1 character is allowed to *not* occur a multiple of 2 times.

So for the 3 given examples:

"mmo", odd length, `m` occurs twice (multiple of 2), `o` occurs once (not a multiple of 2), so `True`.

"yakak", odd length, `a` occurs twice (multiple of 2), `k` occurs twice (multiple of 2), `y` occurs once (not a multiple of 2) , so `True`.

"travel", more than one character does not occur a multiple of 2, so `False`.

Additional examples:

"mmorpg", only `m` occurs a multiple of 2, the rest only once, so `False`.

"mmom", no characters occur a multiple of 2, more than one character occurs "not a multiple of 2 times", so `False`.

At this point you should realise that if only 1 character is allowed to occur a non-multiple-of-2 times, then you can disregard the length. A string with an even length will have either 2 or more characters occuring a non-multiple-of-2 times, or none at all.

So the final rule should be this:

> If at most 1 unique character occurs a non-multiple-of-2 times in the input, the output is `True` otherwise the output is `False`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def can_permutation_palindrome(s):
    counter = {}
    for c in s:
        counter[c] = counter.get(c, 0) + 1
    odd_count = 0
    for count in counter.values():
        odd_count += count % 2
    return odd_count in [0, 1]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: A Python approach would benefit from using `collections.Counter`, which this basically does.

Answer (score 2):

```
def check(string):
    bv = 0
    for s in string:
        bv ^= 1 << ord(s)
    return bv == 0 or bv & (bv - 1) == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I reached the solution below today (python). I think it's readable, and performance-wise it's really good.

```
sum(map(lambda x: word.count(x) % 2, set(word))) <= 1
```

We're basically counting the number of occurrences of each character in the string "word", getting the remainder of the division by 2, summing them all and checking if you have at most 1 of them.

The idea is that you need to have all characters paired, except potentially for one (the middle one).

Answer (score 0):

My idea is, if the number of letters with odd count is one and rest all have even count, a palindrome is possible..Here's my program in Python

```
string = raw_input()

found = False
char_set = set(string) # Lets find unique letters

d_dict = {}
for c in char_set:
    d_dict[c] = string.count(c) # Keep count of each letter

odd_l = [e for e in d_dict.values() if e%2 == 1] # Check how many has odd number of occurrence     
if len(odd_l) >1:
    pass
else:
    found = True



if not found:
    print("NO")
else:
    print("YES")
```

Answer (score 0):

Any string can be palindrome only if at most one character occur odd no. of times and all other characters must occur even number of times. The following program can be used to check whether a palindrome can be string or not.

```
void checkPalindrome(string s)
{
vector<int> vec(256,0);    //Vector for all ASCII characters present.
for(int i=0;i<s.length();++i)
{
    vec[s[i]-'a']++;
}
int odd_count=0,flag=0;
for(int i=0;i<vec.size();++i)
{
    if(vec[i]%2!=0)
        odd_count++;
    if(odd_count>1)
    {
        flag=1;
         cout<<"Can't be palindrome"<<endl;
        break;  
    }
}
if(flag==0)
    cout<<"Yes can be palindrome"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With O(n) complexity .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PallindromePemutation
{
    class charcount
    {
        public char character { get; set; }
        public int occurences { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<charcount> list = new List<charcount>();
            charcount ch;
            int count = 0;
            char[] arr = "travel".ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                charcount res = list.Find(x => x.character == arr.ElementAt(i));
                if (res == null)
                {
                    ch = new charcount();
                    ch.character = arr.ElementAt(i);
                    ch.occurences = 1;
                    list.Add(ch);
                }
                else
                {
                    charcount temp=  list.Find(x => x.character == arr.ElementAt(i));
                    temp.occurences++;
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (!(item.occurences % 2 == 0))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("false");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("true");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we don't care case sensitivity of characters and spaces within a string, then a sample solution in C# by using Dictionary can be like :

```
    private static bool IsPalindromePermutation(string inputStr)
    {
        // First, check whether input string is null or whitespace.
        // If yes, then return false.
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputStr))
            return false;

        var inputDict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        // Big/small letter is not important
        var lowerInputStr = inputStr.ToLower();

        // Fill input dictionary
        // If hit a space, then skip it
        for (var i = 0; i < lowerInputStr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lowerInputStr[i] != ' ')
            {
                if (inputDict.ContainsKey(lowerInputStr[i]))
                    inputDict[lowerInputStr[i]] += 1;
                else
                    inputDict.Add(lowerInputStr[i], 1);
            }
        }

        var countOdds = 0;
        foreach(var elem in inputDict)
        {
            if(elem.Value % 2 != 0)
                countOdds++;
        }

        return countOdds <= 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can acheive this via collections also

```
String name = "raa";
        List<Character> temp = new ArrayList<>(name.chars()
                .mapToObj(e -> (char) e).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < temp.size(); j++) {
                if (temp.get(i).equals(temp.get(j))) {
                    temp.remove(j);
                    temp.remove(i);
                    i--;
                }

            }

        }

        if (temp.size() <= 1) {
            System.out.println("Pallindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println(temp.size());
            System.out.println("Not Pallindrome");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        char val = input.charAt(i);
        if (characters.contains(val)){
            characters.remove(characters.indexOf(val));
        } else{
            characters.add(val);
        }
    }
    if (characters.size() == 1 || characters.size() == 0){
        System.out.print("Yes");
    } else{
        System.out.print("No");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks Java, which you might mention. Have a look at `Edit 4` in [Mureinik's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31224787/3789665) answer - just lacks a [doc comment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide) in my eyes. Don't write, never publish uncommented code!

Answer (score 0):

That 's my solution. The string could contain several words with spaces, such as
Input: Tact Coa
Output true
Input: Tact Coa vvu
Output: false

```
public static boolean checkForPalindrome(String str) {
    String strTrimmed = str.replaceAll(" ","");
    System.out.println(strTrimmed);
    char[] str1 = strTrimmed.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        str1[i] = Character.toLowerCase(str1[i]);
    }

    Arrays.sort(str1);
    String result = new String(str1);
    System.out.println(result);
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < str1.length; j += 2) {
    if (j != str1.length-1) {
        if (str1[j] != str1[j+1]) {
            count++;
            j++;

        }
    } else {
        count++;
    }
   }        
    if (count > 1) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question: Can a String become a palindrome?
Method1: count of characters
IN Java :

```
public class TEST11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "Protijayi";

        int[] count = new int[256];
        Arrays.fill(count, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            char ch = a.charAt(i);
            count[ch]++;
        } // for
            // counting of odd letters
        int odd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
            if ((count[i] & 1) == 1) {
                odd++;
            }

        } // for
        if (odd > 1) {
            System.out.println("no");
        } else {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }

    }

}
```

IN Python:

```
def fix (a):
    count = [0] * 256
    for i in a: count[ord(i)] += 1
    # counting of odd characters
    odd = 0 
    for i in range(256): 
        if((count[i] & 1) == 1): odd += 1

    if(odd > 1):print("no")
    else:print("yes")


a = "Protijayi"

fix(a)
```

Method 2 : Use of HashSet
In Java:

```
public class TEST11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a = "Protijayi";
        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (char ch : a.toCharArray()) {

            if (set.contains(ch)) {
                set.remove(ch);
            }
            set.add(ch);
        } // for

        if (set.size() <= 1) {
            System.out.println("yes can be a palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift example for this question.

```
var str = "mmoosl"
extension String {
func count(of needle: Character) -> Int {
    return reduce(0) {
        $1 == needle ? $0 + 1 : $0
    }
}
}



func canBeTurnedIntoAPalinpolyString(_ polyString: String) -> Bool {
var centerUsed = false
var center = Character("a")
for i in polyString {
    let count  = polyString.count(of: i)
    if count == 1 && !centerUsed {
        center = i
        centerUsed = true
    } else {
        if count % 2 != 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
}
 return true
}

print(canBeTurnedIntoAPalinpolyString(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Java

```
private static boolean isStringPalindromePermutation(String input) {

    if(input == null) return false;

    if(input.isEmpty()) return false;

    int checker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        int character = input.charAt(i) - 'a';

        int oneShiftedByNumberInCharacter = 1 << character;

        int summaryAnd = checker & oneShiftedByNumberInCharacter;
        if ( summaryAnd > 0 ) {
            int revertToShiftedByChar = ~oneShiftedByNumberInCharacter;
            checker = checker & revertToShiftedByChar;
        } else {
            checker |= oneShiftedByNumberInCharacter;
        }
    }
    if ( input.length() % 2 == 0 ) {
        if ( checker == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    } else {
        int checkerMinusOne = checker-1;
        if((checkerMinusOne & checker) == 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a suffix tree or any other data structure?

The **basic requirement of a palindromic string** is the **frequency of all characters** **must be even** **or only one character can have odd frequency**.

**Example** :-

*Input* : aabbaa

*Output* : frequency of a is 4 and b is 2           (both even)

*Input* : xxzyzxx

*Output* : frequency of x is 4, z is 2 and y=1      (only 1 odd)

**Sample code for better understanding :**

```
bool ispalin(string str)                      //function to check
{ 
int freq[26] = {0};               //to store frequency of character here i am
                                          // considering only lower case letters 
for (int i = 0; str.length();  i++) 
    freq[str[i]]++; 
int odd = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)      //Count odd occurring characters 
{ 
    if (freq[i] & 1)                       //checking if odd
        odd++; 
    if (odd > 1)                          //if number of odd freq is greater than 1
        return false; 
}  
return true;                             //else return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

python code to check whether a palindrome can be formed from given string or not:

```
test_str = input('enter any string = ')
count = 0 
for item in set(test_str):
    if test_str.count(item)%2 != 0:
        count+=1 
if (count>1):
    print(" palindrome cannot be formed")
else:
    print(" palindrome can be formed")
```

Please try this code if any issue please comments

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
That is not answering the question. The question is whether a permutation can become a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

**More efficient implementation - Java**

```
boolean palindromeRearranging(String inputString) {
    Map<Character, Integer> charsCount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for(char c : inputString.toCharArray()){
        charsCount.compute(c, (key, val) ->  val == null ? 1 : val + 1);
    }
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    charsCount.forEach((k, v) -> {
        if(v % 2 != 0){
            result.add(v);
        }
    });
    return (result.size() == 0 || result.size() == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code :

```
 boolean palindromeRearranging(String inputString) {
        HashMap<Character,Integer> stCount=new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<inputString.length();i++){
            stCount.put(inputString.charAt(i),0);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<inputString.length();i++){
            int c= stCount.get(inputString.charAt(i));
            stCount.put(inputString.charAt(i),++c);
        }
        int c=0;
        for (Map.Entry<Character,Integer> entry : stCount.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getValue()%2!=0){
                c++;
                if(c>1){
                    return false;
                }
            }   
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For iterating "characters" in a String s, I like `for (int c: s.codepoints())`. The idiom for "counting elements" may be `stCount.merge(c, 1, Integer::sum)`. When you don't need the key, just iterate `stCount.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

JS solution:

```
function solution(inputString) {
  const arr = inputString.split('');
  let hasCoupleList = arr.map( (el) =>  arr.filter( (el1) => el1 == el).length % 2 == 0).filter( (el) => el == false).length;
  return (arr.length % 2 == 0)
    ? hasCoupleList == 0
    : hasCoupleList == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With JAVA

```js
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
//Classs
class Permutation {

  /*
   *  We need to have an even number of almost all characters, 
   *  so that half can be on one side and half can be on the other side.
   *  At most one character (the middle character) can have an odd count.
   */
  public static boolean hasPalindrome(String str) {

    boolean wasOdd = false;
    for (Character c: str.toCharArray()) {

      int counter = 0;
      for (Character cc: str.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == cc) {
          counter++;
        }
      }

      if (counter % 2 == 1) {
        if (wasOdd) {
          return false;
        }
        wasOdd = true;
      }
    }


    return true;

  }
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


    //Taking string input 
    //Scanner
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = s.nextLine();
    if (Permutation.hasPalindrome(str)) {
      System.out.println("YES"); // Writing output to STDOUT

    } else {
      System.out.println("NO"); // Writing output to STDOUT


    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation from [Checking if a String is a Permutation of a Palindrome](https://www.nginflow.com/blog/string-is-a-permutation-of-a-palindrome)

> Time complexity is essentially O(n). This means that the function is linear in the length of the input string

```
public static boolean isPermutationOfPalindrome(String str) {
    // Convert the input string to lower case and remove any non-letter characters
    str = str.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");

    // Create an array to count the frequency of each letter
    int[] charCounts = new int[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        charCounts[str.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
    }

    // Check if there is at most one character with an odd frequency
    boolean foundOdd = false;
    for (int count : charCounts) {
        if (count % 2 == 1) {
            if (foundOdd) {
                return false;
            }
            foundOdd = true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular language defining the meaning of the code presented? Please state in the answer. Does it add anything to [Mureinik's accepted 2015 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31224787)? (note the syntax colouring/language hints there)